# counting of elements (strings) in list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, count

```
genres_list = ['rock', 'pop', 'folk', 'dance', 'rusrap', 'ruspop', 'world', 'electronic', 'alternative', 'children', 'rnb', 'hip', 'jazz','postrock', 'latin', 'classical', 'metal', 'reggae', 'tatar','blues','pop', 'jazz']

# write function to count the number of specific genre in genres_list 

def find_genre(genre):
    count=0
    for count in genres_list:
        if count == genre:
            count=count+1
    return count

number=find_genre(pop)
print(number)
```

output:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: This line `for count in genres_list:` makes `count` a string.

Comment: And when you fix that, this line `number=find_genre(pop)` will show a next error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. `list` has a method to count the number occurences of an element.

```
genres_list = ['rock', 'pop', 'folk', 'dance', 'rusrap', 'ruspop', 'world', 'electronic', 'alternative', 'children', 'rnb', 'hip', 'jazz','postrock', 'latin', 'classical', 'metal', 'reggae', 'tatar','blues','pop', 'jazz']

print(genres_list.count('pop'))
```

---

output

```
2
```

`list.count()` complexity is `O(n)`.

You can write your own count function.

```
def find_genre(genre):
    count=0
    for _genre in genres_list:
        if _genre==genre:
            count+=1
    return count

print(find_genre('pop'))
#2
```

---

`timeit` analysis over a list of size 2 million. Results as of this writing (python 3.7, windows 10)

```
In [38]: timeit genres_list.count('pop') #My answer
26.6 ms ± 939 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [40]: timeit Counter(genres_list)['pop'] #Pitto's answer using collections.Counter
92.5 ms ± 751 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Now, custom count function everyone suggested including me.

```
def find_genre(genre):
    count=0
    for _genre in genres_list:
        if _genre==genre:
            count+=1
    return count
```

---

```
In [42]: timeit find_genre('pop')
63.9 ms ± 803 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Just for the sake of comparison**(<sub>Which I don't recommend using</sub>) I wrote some other functions to calculate count.

```
In [36]: timeit sum(list(map(lambda x:x=='pop',genres_list)))
334 ms ± 13.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [37]: timeit len(list(filter(lambda x:x=='pop',genres_list)))
188 ms ± 18.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [44]: timeit ' '.join(genres_list).count('pop')
41.5 ms ± 2.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Error occurred in your code because you use `count` for calculating the count of a genre and again you used `count` as a looping variable. In every iteration `count` becomes a `str` and we can't add `str` to a `int` type.

Comment: @Ch3steR: Might it be that the timeit comparison is not really fair? As in this case, the creation of the `Counter()` element is fairly expensive as it hashes over all elements (i guess it does something like `counts = {element: element_list.count(element) for element in set(element_list)}` only optimized to `O(n)`) which is slow at the creation but then as `O(1)` for the count lookup?

Comment: @BStadlbauet Counter takes `O(n)` to build. Think of it this way every time a new key is encountered it's value corresponding to key is set to 1. If the key is already in present increase its count by 1. The time complexity is `O(n)`. And to check if a key is present or not takes constant time `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Counter to achieve this result:

```
import collections

genres_list = ['rock', 'pop', 'folk', 'dance', 'rusrap', 'ruspop', 'world', 'electronic', 'alternative', 'children', 'rnb', 'hip', 'jazz','postrock', 'latin', 'classical', 'metal', 'reggae', 'tatar','blues','pop', 'jazz']

counted = collections.Counter(genres_list)
print(counted['rock'])
```

**Output**
1

Another possible solution, if you specifically want to fix your current approach:

```
def find_genre(genre):
    count=0
    for current_genre in genres_list:
        if current_genre == genre:
            count=count+1
    return count

number=find_genre('pop')
print(number)
```

**Output**
2

Your main issue was that naming the for loop variable in the same way that you named the counter variable was confusing you (and was behaving differently too).

As pointed out in comment from Johnny Mop:

> This line **for count in genres_list:** makes count a string.

Comment: Nice use of `Counter` as it calculates *count* of each element in `O(n)`. +1 .

Answer (score 0):

As Johnny Mopp already pointed out in the comments, `for count in genres_list` overwrites your `count` variable to be a string, so you could either do:

```
def find_genre(searched_genre):
    count=0
    for genre in genres_list:
        if searched_genre == genre:
            count = count+1
    return count

number = find_genre('pop')
print(number)
```

Or in a more pythonic way using list comprehension:

```
def find_genre(searched_genre):
    return len([genre for genre in genres_list if genre == searched_genre])
```

Or use a collection as @Pitto suggested (which might not be as intuitive when you first start programming)

Comment: Nice solution here, +1. If we want to be helping new programmers then I'd like to add that list comprehensions are not easy either :) (check it well because I think you are missing brackets)

Comment: Your pythonic way will not work unless you force a list comprehension with square brackets: `len([...])`

Comment: @Pitto: True that, it is probably also fairly slow compared to your `collections.Counter()` method!

Comment: @MatiasCicero: Thanks for the hint, you are right of course! I thought `len()` might be able to iterate over a generator, but just looked up that elements have to provide the `__len__()` dunder method

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using the same variable name in your iteration as the index in your list.

Second, you should use apostrophes in the argument `pop` like this `'pop'`.

Hope this helps:

```py
genres_list = ['rock', 'pop', 'folk', 'dance', 'rusrap', 'ruspop', 'world', 'electronic', 'alternative', 'children', 'rnb', 'hip', 'jazz','postrock', 'latin', 'classical', 'metal', 'reggae', 'tatar','blues','pop', 'jazz']

# write function to count the number of specific genre in genres_list
def find_genre(genre):
    num=0
    for count in genres_list:
        if count == genre:
            num=num+1
    return num

number=find_genre('pop')
print(number)
```